# MOSFET Saturation

Tags: transistors

I'm looking at the following circuit diagram
[image]

Where the given parameters are:
$$V_{DD} =  1.8V$$
$$R_D = 8k$$
$$V_{GS} = 0.65V$$
$$V_t=0.4V$$
$$k_n=4ma/V^2$$

I was told to find the DC current I(D). However I'm not sure how we know which mode the transistor is in. I understand that saturation is when:

$$V_{DS} > V_{GS} - V_t$$

and triode is when

$$V_{DS} < V_{GS} - V_t$$

Yet how can I determine which mode the transistor is in if I am not given V(DS)?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on which mode you are in, you have two different equations for Id. Also Vds in this case, is the same as Vd because Vs = 0V.

You write Vd in terms of Id.

$$ V_{ds} = V_{dd}-R_d*I_d $$

The thing with these types of circuits is that, its a guessing game. You have to assume on mode of operation, and use the equations for that mode. The math will tell you if you guessed right or wrong. If its wrong, change your mode and redo the calculation with the new mode.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that Rd is insignificant and Vdd is high enough to saturate the FET, then calculate what Id would be. Now calculate what Vds would be with that current flowing from Vdd through Rd. Which region is the FET in now?